# Getting ID of collapsed div, in Toggle event

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs setup, with headers and content.
When you click the header, it expands the content on the selected div, and hides all others.
This works fine, but I need to get the ID's of all the content divs, that have been hidden or shown.

This is my jquery for the hide/show:

```
$(".CollapsableHeader").next(".CollapsableDiv").hide();
            $(".CollapsableHeader").click(function () {
                $('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.CollapsableDiv').slideToggle(300, function () {
                    alert($(this).next('.CollapsableDiv').attr('id'));
                });
                $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");

            });
```

So, in this example, my alert always comes up as, `undefined`.
Everything I have tried, comes up as `undefined`. 
Any idea how I can get the ID's of the `.CollapsableDiv`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the `id` of the "next" `.CollapsableDiv` after the `.CollapsableHeader` that was clicked, grab it in the click handler rather than the `slideToggle` callback:

```
$(".CollapsableHeader").next(".CollapsableDiv").hide();
            $(".CollapsableHeader").click(function () {
                // Grab it here
                var id = $(this).next('.CollapsableDiv').attr('id');
                $('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.CollapsableDiv').slideToggle(300, function () {
                    // Then use it here
                    alert(id);
                });
                $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");

            });
```

The reason is that the `this` within your `slideToggle` callback is a different element (specifically, it's whatever you end up with from `$('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.CollapsableDiv')`.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. It's the .CollapsableDiv I need.

Comment: @Nicolai: My opening sentence was a bit off (fixed now), but that is the `id` the code above grabs, the one of the next `.CollapsableDiv`.

Comment: Oh right, I should have read your actual code, instead of just your comments. :)